# How can I explain the unexpected negative voltage in the output signal obtained from half wave rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, sine, square

I observed the output signal of half-wave rectifier sending sine wave and square wave for an experiment. The rectifier was built with a 1N 4001 diode and a 100 ohm resistor. The output signal across the resistor was observed.

In both of the output signals displayed by the oscilloscope, negative voltage was observed. While the negative voltage in output sine signal was minor, the negative voltage observed in output square signal was much more obvious, in fact it goes beyond the maximum positive voltage.

In the output signal there is also a minor increase in the negative voltage when frequency increases, which I can't explain either.

Comment: Hint: reverse recovery.

Comment: Hint : real world diodes are not ideal and don't work at speed of light to do their rectifying. Besides, shouldn't you be doing your own research instead of asking here for an answer to schoolwork?

Comment: It's worth knowing there are much faster diodes (much lower reverse recovery time) for jobs that need them, like switching supplies, or your square wave example.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that this effect is dependent on the inductance of the current paths. With enough inductance, the voltage spikes could break circuit components. I've seen expensive destruction wrought by this phenomenon. You could learn a lot by understanding where the energy in those spikes is coming from, and how to limit the voltage spikes.

Answer (score 8):

The 1N400x type diode has a reverse recovery time (manufacturer dependent) of up to 30 μs and, when your input voltage falls negative, the diode will continue to conduct for up to 30 μs: -

[image]